# JBoss EAP 6.1 Runtime Server

Tags: java, jboss

I am  using JBoss EAP 6.1 Runtime Server.

Could you please help me how to make auto deployment when i build the code in eclipse ,Because when i change any java code or xhtml i need to run maven build and copy the war file into jboss deployment folder.

Eclipese Version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Jboss setting:

Publishing setting:
Automatically publish after every build

I am not able to attach the screen shot due to 10 reputation

Thanks you.

Comment: Take a look in standalone.xml to the deployment-scanner `<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>`, perhaps is set to false, or scan-interval to 0 (or too high)

Comment: `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
        </subsystem> `

Still i have the problem

Thanks